# How to get the id of the run from within a component?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm doing some experimentation with Kubeflow Pipelines and I'm interested in retrieving the run id to save along with some metadata about the pipeline execution. Is there any way I can do so from a component like a `ContainerOp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to do this using the [Python's DSL](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.dsl.html) but seems that isn't possible right now.

The only option that I found is to use the method that they used in [this sample code](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/cce52f4dfbac09b73e6af617fcb82b2df35ba16c/samples/kubeflow-tf/kubeflow-training-classification.py#L44). You basically declare a string containing `{{workflow.uid}}`. It will be replaced with the actual value during execution time.

You can also do this in order to get the pod name, it would be `{{pod.name}}`.

Comment: It seems that the supported placeholders are these listed in Argo's doc: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/docs/variables.md

Comment: More correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673458/1497385

Comment: {{pod.name}} is not relative to the run, but to the component.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `kfp.dsl.EXECUTION_ID_PLACEHOLDER` and `kfp.dsl.RUN_ID_PLACEHOLDER` as arguments for your component. At runtime they will be replaced with the actual values.

Comment: Thanks. How are these two different?

Comment: RUN_ID is for the whole pipeline run while the EXECUTION_ID is for a single component task execution. It might be better to just use a random number generation component though.

Answer (score 2):

Since kubeflow pipeline relies on argo, you can use argo variable to get what you want.

For example,

```py
@func_to_container_op
def dummy(run_id, run_name) -> str:
    return run_id, run_name

@dsl.pipeline(
    name='test_pipeline',
)
def test_pipeline():
  dummy('{{workflow.labels.pipeline/runid}}', '{{workflow.annotations.pipelines.kubeflow.org/run_name}}')
```

You will find that the placeholders will be replaced with the correct run_id and run_name.

For more argo variables: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/variables.md

To Know what are recorded in the labels and annotation in the kubeflow pipeline run, just get the corresponding workflow from k8s.

```
kubectl get workflow/XXX -oyaml
```

Comment: Neither `workflow.labels` nor  `workflow.annotations` seem to work for me. When attempting to start a run, I'm getting `Internal error: (...) failed to resolve {{workflow.labels.pipeline/runid}}` and the run doesn't even start. Other variables listed in `variables.md` seem to work fine though. I'm on `kfp==1.8.18`, KF 1.6 and Argo v3.3.8.

Comment: same error for me

Answer (score 1):

Your component's container should have an environment variable called `HOSTNAME` that is set to its unique pod name, from which you derive all necessary metadata.

Answer (score 1):

`create_run_from_pipeline_func` which returns `RunPipelineResult`, and has `run_id attribute`

```py
client = kfp.Client(host)
result = client.create_run_from_pipeline_func(…) 
result.run_id
```

Answer (score 1):

For V1:

It seems like `kfp.dsl.EXECUTION_ID_PLACEHOLDER` (component run id) and `kfp.dsl.RUN_ID_PLACEHOLDER` (pipeline run id) will accomplish what you're asking.

[source](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/kfp.dsl.html#module-kfp.dsl)

For V2:

`kfp.v2.dsl.PIPELINE_JOB_ID_PLACEHOLDER` and `kfp.v2.dsl.PIPELINE_TASK_ID_PLACEHOLDER` respectively.

[source](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/master/source/dsl.html)

Comment: Unfortunately for v2 `kfp.v2.dsl.PIPELINE_JOB_ID_PLACEHOLDER` still doesn't work. You still need to use `{{workflow.uid}}`